# How Can know the Size of Image ( Kb) in Action script 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, getimagesize

I am Writing code to load image From Server With a Timer Function Of 2 seconds . I  want to know the Size of Each image . Is it Possible to Know in `ActionScript 3.0`?

enter code here

```
public class Example extends Sprite {
public function Example() {
 var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(2000);
 myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,runMany);
 myTimer.start();
 function runMany(e:TimerEvent):void {
 var loader:Loader=new Loader();
 var url:String= "http:/google.com.example3";
 loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
  addChild(loader);
  }
 }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `contentLoaderInfo.bytesTotal` property of the `Loader` class.

```
trace(loader.contentLoaderInfo.bytesTotal);
```

Or you can add an event handler:

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);

function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    trace(event.bytesTotal);
}
```

Comment: When the file starts to download the bytesTotal property will shows real value. Use second option.

Comment: Why? When you call `loader.load(new URLRequest(url));` the image starts to load.

Comment: to display the image on the loader ..by passing the  url

Comment: in the second method i also get  0

Comment: i have written code..you can check it. it shows the 5 to 6 times for one image . if there is posibility for one time. according to timer.

Comment: @TOM I don't understand. Do you need a help? What is your question?

Comment: the images are coming to the loader accoring to the  timer... i want to see the actual size of image once. what i have written it shows the size from start of loading to end.. i

Comment: Remove the event listener when you get the actual size. `If (event.bytesTotal > 0) removeEventListener(...`

Answer (score 1):

I made a small change on the above code

```
 loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
 function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
 {
    trace(event.bytesLoaded);
  }
```

Instead of  bytestotal. I put bytesloaded. It works and shows the loading.